# Array of objects based on base class passing to a funtion

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to implement a function that operates on multiple types of array of class objects.
Function receives the class array based on base class ptr.
Class array is references and passed to this function to store the array.

I don't want to use templates or any of the STL containers like map, vectors or list etc.
I have below sample program but I get segmentation fault as print function fails to conver the object to specifc type.

How this can be this implemented?

```
#include <string>

typedef enum {
    CLASS_TYPE_1 = 0,
    CLASS_TYPE_2,
    CLASS_TYPE_3, 
    CLASS_TYPE_4 
}ClassType;

class Base {

public:    
    virtual ClassType GetType() = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class ClassType1 : public Base {

public: 
    int index;

    ClassType1(int index) {
        this->index = index;
        printf("ClassType1: index[%d] \n", index);
    }

    virtual ClassType GetType() { 
        return CLASS_TYPE_1;
    };

    virtual void print() {
        printf("print called index[%d] \n", index);    
    }
};


class ClassHolder {

    ClassType type;    
    Base *baseArray;
    int arraySize;

public:

    void setArray(Base *array) {
        this->baseArray = array;
    }

    void setType(ClassType type) {
        this->type = type;
    }

    void setArraySize(int size) {
        this->arraySize = size;
    }

    void print(int index) {
        if (index < arraySize) {
            if (type == CLASS_TYPE_1) {
                //((ClassType1&)baseArray[index]).print(); // <------ Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
            }
            else if(type == CLASS_TYPE_2) {
                //((ClassType2&)baseArray[index]).print(); // <------ Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
            }
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    ClassHolder holder;
    ClassType1 array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    holder.setType(CLASS_TYPE_1);
    holder.setArray(array);
    holder.setArraySize(5);
    holder.print(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Who can I avoid the fault?

Comment: An array of `ClassType1` is not an array of `Base`. You need an array of `Base*`.

Comment: your cast is wrong, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  ((ClassType1&)baseArray[index]).draw();
> ```

must be replaced by

```
((ClassType1 *)baseArray)[index].print();
```

the *cast* `(ClassType1&)baseArray[index]` is wrong because you use *baseArray* as a `Base*` and it is not that, you have to indicate *baseArray* is a `ClassType1 *` to access it in a right way